# Click image to display actual size

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have images saved to a SQL  database. My plan is to have 3 image fields in the database. I want to display the images and be able to click on the image to display the actual image in a new view - actual size. I think I am close with my code, but when I click on the image it does nothing. Can someone see anything wrong? Below is the codes.
reagards,
SEB

View:

```
    @model PBTIntranet.Models.Swap

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<style type="text/css">
    .thumb {
        max-width: 500px;
        max-height: 500px;
        width: expression(this.width > 100 ? "500px" : true);
        height: expression(this.height > 100 ? "500px" : true);
    }
</style>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("img").click(function () {
     var src = $(this).attr("src");
     alert("it works!");
      $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/Swap/ShowImage",
                data: { "src": src},
                datatype: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function () {
                    window.location.href = "/Swap/ShowImage";
                },
            });
 });
});
</script>

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Swap Shop</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Item)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContactInfo)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ContactInfo)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Seller)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Seller)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ExpireDate)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ExpireDate)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image)*@
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @if (@Model.Image != null)
            {
                string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image);
                string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
                <img class="thumb" src="@imageSrc" />
            }
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.ID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult ShowImage(string src)
    {
        string imageSrc = "";
        if (src != null)
        {
            Session["src"] = src;
        }
        imageSrc = Session["src"].ToString();
        return View((object)imageSrc);
    }
```

ShowImage:

```
@model PBTIntranet.Models.Swap

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowImage";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ShowImage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="@Model" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **ShowImage** view expects the object **Swap** but I see that in your controller action you pass a string that you (unnecessarily) cast as an object. So when you post the data via AJAX, you're getting a 500 Internal Server Error, which jQuery's AJAX shows you as a generic error with no helpful message. (Just take a look in the console, you'll see the error). Your view should be defined as:

```
@model string
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowImage";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ShowImage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="@Model" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the change is on the first line:

```
@model string
```

instead of

```
@model PBTIntranet.Models.Swap
```

If this doesn't work, than you might have other errors as well. If it does resolve your problem, don't forget to vote up, please. Whatever the case, please let me know.

Comment: That was it. Thanks a bunch!!